# Css print stylesheet, remove date but keep margin

Tags: css

There are some answers here on SO showing how to remove the header/footer from a page in print using something like the following:

```
@page {
  margin: 0;
}
```

While this indeed removes the date/sidenr from the page it has a drawback. This also removes the margin from the page which means that the content starts right at the top of the page.

Is possible to remove the header/footer but still get some margins on the page in order to make it look better?

Comment: What about `@media print { #footer { display:none; } }` https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: Thank you for answering,  i think that you suggestion will only apply if I have an element with id #footer. Im looking to remove the date and pagenr which I think is added by the browser or printer.

Comment: You're right about how my suggestion would apply — it was not clear (to me) from your question that you meant the _browser_ headers and footers. You could improve your question by making that clearer. (and maybe link to "some answers here on SO")

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by assigning margin to a different containing element:

```
@page { size: auto; margin: 0mm; }

@media print{
    body{ margin: 4cm; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Serge, i will try this tomorrow.

Comment: This works only if the document doesn't have more than one page, doesn't it?